# How to use q.defer in node.js to chain promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  var location_parent_id = req.params.location_parent_id;

  var query = {
    company_id: req.company_id
  };

  if(location_parent_id) {
    query.location_parent_id = location_parent_id;
    Location.findOne({someQuery}, function(err, location) {
      response.location = location;
    });
  } else {
    query.location_parent_id = {
      '$exists': false
    }
  }

  Location.find(query, function(err, locations) {
    if(err) {
      response = {
        status: 'error',
        error: err
      }
    } else if(!locations) {
      response = {
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Location not found'
      }
    } else {
      response = {
        status: 'ok',
        locations: locations
      }
      return res.json(response);
    }
  });
}
```

That's my code. If there is a `location_parent_id`, then I want to return that location as well. Rather than getting into async and callback hell, I figure promises are a good way to execute what I want. Just not sure of exactly how.

Comment: You use `then` to chain promises. Use `q.defer` only to create them (if at all).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `q.defer` at all. You can use the [Node-callback interface methods](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) to get promises right away. To chain the methods, use `.then()`.

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  var result = Q.ninvoke(Location, "find", {
    company_id: req.company_id,
    location_parent_id: req.params.location_parent_id || {'$exists': false}
  }).then(function(locations) {
    if (!locations)
      throw new Error('Location not found');
    return {
      status: 'ok',
      locations: locations
    };
  });
  if (req.params.location_parent_id) {
    // insert the step to wait for the findOne (in parallel), and merge into res
    result = Q.all([result, Q.ninvoke(Location, "findOne", {someQuery})])
    .spread(function(res, location) {
      res.location = location;
      return res;
    });
  }
  result.catch(function(err) {
    return {
      status: 'error',
      error: err.message
    };
  }).done(function(response) {
    res.json(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: Have a weird ` }).catch(;`

Comment: Please do not `throw` strings, while some promises hack around in order to give you stack traces for them - it's bad practice. (Also, Q is not one of those libraries and you lose all stack trace when you throw a string)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks for the heads-up! Better now?

Comment: Yeah, clever solution by the way. The only thing that bothers me is the performance now, but that's a Q problem, not a promises or solution problem :) Oh, one more thing, location_parent_id is used in the `if` but you did not define it since you moved it into the `.ninvoke`

Comment: `then is not defined` on:   `}).done(then(function(response) {`